# How add automatically [img] tag in my links?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how to add [img] tag in my links. I want to load in the box only link e.g. like:

```
http://site com/images/image1.jpg
http://site com/images/image2.jpg
http://site com/images/image3.jpg
```

**then you want those url to be converted automatically to**

```
[img]http://site com/images/image1.jpg[/img]
[img]http://site com/images/image2.jpg[/img]
[img]http://site com/images/image3.jpg[/img]
```

If you use this code works perfectly but only the first image is displayed

```
[xfgiven_screenshot]
<div id="section-Screenshot" class="fullfeature">
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="screenshots"><img src="[xfvalue_screenshot]" alt="" /></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
[/xfgiven_screenshot]
```

What should I do to display the rest of the links for images?

Thanks for help!

Comment: What's this? Datalife Engine?

Comment: Yes, use Datalife Engine, for this I need.